# Display Task Historic Data

Tags: versioning, tasks

I have a Tasks list with versioning enabled. Each task goes through several states (Not Started, In Progress, Completed).

Is there an easy way to display for a given task its timeline? For example I'd like to see in a single table all the task changes:

```
Modified   |   State     |
03/05/2012 | Not Started |
03/06/2012 | In Progress |
03/12/2012 | Completed   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using object model in custom web part. Versioned data can be accessed using `SPListItemVersionCollection` class. You can get to know how its used to get versions of each list item [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemversioncollection.aspx).

Retrieving the Status column and the Modified column in a tabular format would bring you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted Deepu's answer, but in my case a custom Web Part was not an option.

My workaround was to use a workflow to:

- either copy the state field to a comments field with append changes enabled
- or copy the task to another list to create a log list

Apparently Web services are not an option, there is no service to retrieve list item versions.

[Update] it seems that there's actually a way to retrieve version history of list items. Here is a link to SPServices that explains it:

http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/284298?ProjectName=spservices

Comment: Thats another way of doing it. Thanks for the post Chris.